# How to find the number of occurences within a date range?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I have hospital visits in the table TestData

I would like to know which patients have had a second hospital visit within 7 days of their first hospital visit.

How would I code this in SQL?
I have patient_id as a TEXT
the date is date_visit is also TEXT and takes the format MM/DD/YYYY

| patient_id | date_visit |
| --- | --- |
| A123B29133 | 07/12/2011 |
| A123B29133 | 07/14/2011 |
| A123B29133 | 07/20/2011 |
| A123B29134 | 12/05/2016 |

In the above table patient A123B29133 fulfills the condition as they were seen on 07/14/2011 which is less that 7 days from 07/12/2011

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. You have to convert the TEXT values in order to do numeric comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery with `exists`:

```
with to_d(id, v_date) as (
    select patient_id, substr(date_visit, 7, 4)||"-"||substr(date_visit, 1, 2)||"-"||substr(date_visit, 4, 2) from visits
)
select t2.id from (select t1.id, min(t1.v_date) d1 from to_d t1 group by t1.id) t2
where exists (select 1 from to_d t3 where t3.id = t2.id and t3.v_date != t2.d1 and t3.v_date <= date(t2.d1, '+7 days'))
```

| id |
| --- |
| A123B29133 |

Answer (score 1):

Since your date column is not in YYYY-MM-DD which is the default value used by several sqlite date functions, the `substr` function was used to transform your date in this format. `JulianDay` was then used to convert your dates to an integer value which would ease the comparison of 7 days. The `MIN` window function was used to identify the first hospital visit date for that patient. The demo fiddle and samples show the query that was used to transform the data and the results before the final query which filters based on your requirements i.e. `< 7 days`. With this approach using window functions, you may also retrieve the visit_date and the number of days since the first visit date if desired.

You may read more about sqlite date functions [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    patient_id,
    visit_date,
    JulianDay(visit_date) - 
    MIN(JulianDay(visit_date)) OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id)
     as num_of_days_since_first_visit
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            *,
            (
              substr(date_visit,7) || '-' ||
              substr(date_visit,0,3) || '-' ||
              substr(date_visit,4,2)
            ) as visit_date
        FROM
            visits
    ) v;
```

| patient_id | visit_date | num_of_days_since_first_visit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A123B29133 | 2011-07-12 | 0 |
| A123B29133 | 2011-07-14 | 2 |
| A123B29133 | 2011-07-20 | 8 |
| A123B29134 | 2016-12-05 | 0 |

---

**Query #2**

The below is your desired query, which uses the previous query as a CTE and applies the filter for visits less than 7 days. `num_of_days <> 0` is applied to remove entries where the first date is also the date of the record.

```
WITH num_of_days_since_first_visit AS (
SELECT
    patient_id,
    visit_date,
    JulianDay(visit_date) - MIN(JulianDay(visit_date)) OVER (PARTITION BY patient_id) num_of_days
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            *,
            (
              substr(date_visit,7) || '-' ||
              substr(date_visit,0,3) || '-' ||
              substr(date_visit,4,2)
            ) as visit_date
        FROM
            visits
    ) v
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    patient_id
FROM
    num_of_days_since_first_visit
WHERE
    num_of_days <> 0 AND num_of_days < 7;
```

| patient_id |
| --- |
| A123B29133 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bq29Sg9CqnMe8B5KLwm4Ux/4)

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know which patients have had a second hospital visit within 7 days of their first hospital visit.

You can use `lag()`.  The following gets all rows where this is true:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(date_visit) over (partition by patient_id order by date_visit) as prev_date_visit
      from t
     ) t
where prev_date_visit >= date(date_visit, '-7 day');
```

If you just want the `patient_id`s, you can use `select distinct patient_id`.